Clarification of estimates of $H^1$ norm and $H^{-1}$ norm.
Consider the following Dirichlet Problem for $u' \in H^1(\Omega)$
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
Lu' = f, \qquad \mbox{in }  \quad\Omega \qquad (1)\\
u' = 0, \qquad \mbox{on } \quad \partial \Omega,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $\Omega$ is a domain with Lipschitz boundary $\partial \Omega$ and $L$ is the elliptic operator given by
\begin{equation}
L := -\mbox{div}(A(\nabla \cdot)) + c, \qquad \mbox{in } \Omega,
\end{equation}
for some complex-symmetric matrix A and complex-valued function $c$. Say $u$ is the solution to
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
Lu = 0, \qquad \mbox{in }  \quad\Omega \qquad \\
u = -v, \qquad \mbox{on } \quad \partial \Omega,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
for $v \in H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ with an extension to $\Omega$ given by $v' \in H^1(\Omega)$. Then if $f = -Lv'$, from Sobolev Bound for solution to Dirichlet Problem from knowledge of boundary estimates we have
\begin{equation}
|| u' ||_{H^1(\Omega)} \leq C ||f||_{H^{-1}(\Omega)} \qquad (2)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
|| f ||_{H^{-1}(\Omega)} \leq C || v' ||_{H^{1}(\Omega)} \qquad (3)
\end{equation}
Assuming $u'$ exists, I am confused about where (2) and (3) come from. The answer in the link above says that (2) can be obtained by multiplying $Lu'$ by $u$ and integrating. However, I don't see how this works? How do the $H^{1}$ and $H^{-1}$ norms come out of doing this. As for (3), I am not sure where this comes from either as it is not mentioned in linked question as far as I can see.

More precise assumptions on $A$ and $c$ are needed, for $(2)$ and $(3)$ do not hold for general complex-valued coefficients $A$ and $c$. My answer below relies on the following (customary) assumptions:
$$ \exists \alpha_1, \alpha_2, c_1, c_2 > 0, \quad c_1 < c < c_2 \quad \text{and} \quad \alpha_1 \leq A \xi \cdot \xi \leq \alpha_2 \ \ \ \forall \xi \in \mathbb{C}^2. $$
Equation $(1)$ multiplied by $\overline{u'}$ and integrated over $\Omega$ gives the following, thanks to the Green's formula for Sobolev spaces applied to $(u', A \nabla u') \in H^1_0(\Omega) \times H(\mathrm{div}; \Omega)$:
$$\int_\Omega \big[ (A \nabla u') \cdot \nabla \overline{u'} + c |u'|^2 \big] d\Omega = \langle f, u' \rangle_{H^{-1}(\Omega), H^1_0(\Omega)}.$$
Estimate $(2)$ then follows on one hand from the ellipticity of $A$ and $c$ (with $\alpha := \min (\alpha_1, c_1) > 0$), and on the other hand from the fact that $f \in H^{-1}(\Omega)$ can be identified to a continuous linear form on $H^1_0(\Omega)$:
$$ \alpha \Vert u'\Vert^2_{H^1(\Omega)} \leq \int_\Omega \big[ (A \nabla u') \cdot \nabla \overline{u'} + c |u'|^2 \big] d\Omega = \big| \langle f, u' \rangle_{H^{-1}(\Omega), H^1_0(\Omega)} \big| \leq \Vert f\Vert_{H^{-1}(\Omega)} \Vert u'\Vert_{H^{1} (\Omega)}.$$
This argument is no longer valid if $c$ is allowed to be $0$, but you can still establish $(2)$ using Poincaré's inequality.
Estimate $(3)$ is obtained by multiplying both sides of the equality $f = -L v$ by any test function $\overline{\varphi} \in H^1_0(\Omega)$, by integrating over $\Omega$, and by using the continuity of the bilinear form $(v, \varphi) \mapsto \langle L v, \varphi \rangle$ (with continuity constant $\beta := \max(\alpha_2, c_2) > 0$):
\begin{align}
\forall \varphi \in H^1_0(\Omega), \quad \langle f, \varphi \rangle_{H^{-1}(\Omega), H^1_0(\Omega)} &= \int_\Omega \big[ (A \nabla v) \cdot \nabla \overline{\varphi} + c v \overline{\varphi} \big] d\Omega \\
&\leq \beta \Vert v\Vert_{H^1(\Omega)} \Vert \varphi\Vert_{H^1(\Omega)}.
\end{align}
I would suggest looking at Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations (Chapter 8) by Brezis, or Partial Differential Equations (Chapter 6) by Evans.

Hi, thank you for your answer, its quite comprehensive. I have two concerns though. 1. I am confused where $\alpha ||u'||^2$ comes from. I thought the ellipticity condition only applied when the two vectors in the dot product are the same - i.e. $A \nabla u' \cdot \nabla u'$ for example. Also, How do you estimate $c$ from below using ellipticity when it is not multiplied by vectors? For the derivation of (3), how do you estimate $< f, \varphi >$ from below? Getting it from above is a Cauchy-Schwarz type estimate but from below I am not too sure?

In retrospect, you need some ellipticity conditions on $A$ and $c$ to have Estimate $(2)$. For a real-valued $A$, I assumed the ellipticity of $A$ to be $(A \xi) \cdot \overline{\xi} \geq \alpha_1 \vert \xi \vert^2$. Also, I defined $a \cdot b := a_1 b_1 + \dots + a_n b_n$ (i.e. the real dot product, not the complex one), which is why I added the complex conjugate in the ellipticity condition.

If, for simplicity, $A$ is real-valued and elliptic in the sense of my first comment, $(2)$ is satisfied if $c$ is bounded from below by a positive constant. If $c$ is only non-negative, you can still obtain $(2)$ using Poincaré's inequality. $(2)$ can also be obtained if $c$ is complex-valued, with a non-vanishing imaginary part. If $c$ takes negative values, then you may have eigenvalues, and $(2)$ does not hold, so more info on your specific $c$ is needed. I edited my answer accordingly.

For $(3)$: By definition of the dual norm, $\Vert f\Vert_{H^{-1}} := \text{sup}{ \langle f, \varphi \rangle_{H^{-1}, H^1_0} / \Vert \varphi \Vert_{H^1}, \ \ \ \varphi \in H^1_0(\Omega) }$. Thus the inequality $\langle f, \varphi \rangle_{H^{-1}, H^1_0} \leq C \Vert \varphi\Vert_{H^1}$ for any $\varphi \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ tells you that $\Vert f \Vert_{H^{-1}} \leq C$.

OK, let me add in assumptions here as they were missing from my OP. Say that "$\cdot$" denotes the real inner product, regardless of whether its between real or complex vectors. Now assume that there is some $C_1/C_2 > 0$ such that $|A(x)|, |c(x)| < C_1$ for any $x \in \Omega$. Also if $A = A_R + i A_I$ (real and imaginary parts of $A$), assume that there is a $C_2 > 0$ such that $C_2 |\xi|^2 \leq A_R(x) \xi \cdot \xi$ and $C_2 |\xi|^2 \leq A_I \xi \cdot \xi$ for $x \in \Omega$. Here $A$ (complex-symmetric also) and $c$ are complex-valued as that is what I am interested in. Are these enough?

For (3), is this not a bound from above? From my understanding about your final inequality, I think we need a bound for $<f,\varphi>{(H^{-1}, H^1_0)}$ from below. My logic is that if we had say $<f,\varphi>{(H^{-1}, H^1_0)} > C||f||{H^{-1}}|| \varphi||{H^1}$ for $C>0$, then from what you have we could write $C||f||{H^{-1}}|| \varphi||{H^1} \leq <f,\varphi>{(H^{-1}, H^1_0)} \leq \beta || v ||{H^1} || \varphi ||{H^1} \implies ||f||{H^{-1}} \leq C(\beta)  || v ||_{H^1}$. I don't see how what you wrote in your response gets us (3) but I am sure I am missing something.
